# onDraw Method not Called?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, ondraw

I am creating a custom view but the onDraw method is never being called. I tried doing this - `setWillNotDraw(false)` but it still doesn't work.

In fact, it doesn't even work after calling `invalidate()`. Here's my code -

```
public class Box extends View {
    public Box (Context context) {
        super (context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {    // Initialize paint object
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(mBoxColor);
        setMeasuredDimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
    }
}
```

My activity code -

```
Box box = new Box(this);
```

Please help

Comment: How are you adding your `Box` to the `Activity`'s `View` hierarchy? It's not going to draw until it's put on-screen.

Comment: Add this.setWillNotDraw(false); in constructor

Comment: setWillNotDraw is ignored for View's subclasses. it Is for ViewGroup's subclasses. you probably didn't add  box to any view

Comment: @MikeM. yes that was the problem :( I feel so stupid now. Thanks everyone for replying. This is the reason why I don't like the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity.java

use

```
setContentView(box);
```